# django database update using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, django-models, beautifulsoup

Im very new to Django. I have been running through tutorials and decided to start on something of my own and need a little advice on the best way forward.

I'm creating a simple site which runs through a small list of URLS stored in a postgreSQL table and uses Beautiful Soup to extract data from each of the URL pages and store it against the record.. (its just stats recorded on the home page of each)

Ive set up the model and the relevant class listview to display them all. About to start running through the beautiful soup part and wondered where should physically put the code to run through and "scrape" the data for each site?

Should it be something called when the class view is called? Some kind of Model Manager? Just a bespoke Function or something? I would like to use Ajax to update this data in intervals if possible so it needs to fit in with that.

Hopefully that's not too vague. Happy to post what i have if you feel that's beneficial although it is literally just a simple model and Class ListView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do any scraping in views. It might confuse the user because the page won't load while the scraping is happening. The user may also refresh the page and cause your code to run twice. Additionally a lot of proxies that you may install for your project may have timeouts.

This is more of a background process type of work. The easiest way to do that is with a [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/). Create a file called `scrape.py` under `management/commands`. Don't forget `__init__.py`. For example:

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            scrape.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

In that file use:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('I am a scraper!'))
```

Finally don't forget to run your new command with:

```
python manage.py scrape
```

You probably want to set it up with a cron job.

For more complex use cases, see [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: Perfect, ill give that a try.  Thanks for the quick response kichik.